# HTML checkbox value is only return 'on'

Tags: javascript, python, html, css

html

```
<FORM NAME="myForm" method="GET" action="{%url 'search_result'%}">
    <label for="F">Female</label><INPUT TYPE="checkbox" NAME="gender" ONCLICK="toggleShow(this)" value="F" id="0">

    <DIV ID="subCats0" CLASS="subCats">
        <INPUT TYPE="checkbox" NAME="age" ONCLICK="toggleShow2(this)" vaule='10' id='10'>
        gender=10
        <div id="sub10" Class="sub">
            <INPUT TYPE="checkbox" NAME="category_name[]" value="c">
            1.c
            <INPUT TYPE="checkbox" NAME="category_name[]" value="a">
            2.a
            <INPUT TYPE="checkbox" NAME="category_name[]" value="d">
            3.d
        </div>
    </DIV>

    <BR>
    <label for="M">Male</label><INPUT TYPE="checkbox" NAME="gender" ONCLICK="toggleShow(this)" id='1' value='M'>
    <BR>
    <DIV ID="subCats1" CLASS="subCats">
        <INPUT TYPE="checkbox" NAME="10">
        gender=10
        </DIV>
         <input type="submit" value="search" id="search_button">
         </FORM>
```

css

```
    .subCats {
        display: none;
        margin-left: 20px;
    }

    .sub {
        display: none;
        margin-left: 20px;
    }
```

javascript

```
 function toggleShow(checkbox) {
        var id = 'subCats' + checkbox.id;
        var subCats =
            document.all ? document.all[id] :
                document.getElementById ? document.getElementById(id) :
                    null;
        if (subCats) {
            if (subCats.style.display == '' ||
                subCats.style.display == 'none')
                subCats.style.display = 'block';
            else
                subCats.style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
    function toggleShow2(checkbox) {
        var id = 'sub' + checkbox.id;
        var sub =
            document.all ? document.all[id] :
                document.getElementById ? document.getElementById(id) :
                    null;
        if (sub) {
            if (sub.style.display == '' ||
                sub.style.display == 'none')
                sub.style.display = 'block';
            else
                sub.style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
```

> when click the submit,
> gender and category_name[] return correct value.
> for example, gender=F&age=on&category_name=b
> But age value is only return 'on'. Even though set the value of the check box, only return 'on'.
> what is problem..? Is the javascript code wrong?

Comment: why `python` and `django` tags when there is not a single line of python code in the question?

Comment: I modified the tag. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a typo, the spelling of attribute 'value' is incorrect in age input and therefore the value for age tag is not specified.

Checkboxes uses 'on' as its default value when checked, that's why you are getting 'on' as value.

replace

```
<INPUT TYPE="checkbox" NAME="age" ONCLICK="toggleShow2(this)" vaule='10' id='10'>
```

with

```
<INPUT TYPE="checkbox" NAME="age" ONCLICK="toggleShow2(this)" value='10' id='10'>
```